# openpyxl returns numeric values

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a Python script using openpyxl to read an excel file. This used to work fine, until I discovered that openpyxl wasn't installed properly, which gave me errors running the script outside my IDE. After fixing this however, the script returns numeric values of which I don't understand where they come from, instead of the real values.

The script:

```
wb=load_workbook(r'C:\test.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

#Iterate trough all rows
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    for cell in row:
        #If the column == A, check if there's a website value
        if cell.column == 'A':
            try:
                print cell.internal_value
                self.match = re.match(regex, cell.internal_value)
                if self.match:
                    self.match = 'OK'
            except:
                pass
```

The print in the try block is added to see what is returned by the program, which is the following for the first five records:

```
0
1
31
49
143
```

It should be:

```
None
Website
www.coolblue.nl
www.bol.com
www.elektrosky.nl
```

Why does my script return these numeric values instead of the actual values?

**EDIT:** First 6 rows of my xml file (first row is empty)

```
Website           |     Sender    |     Price  |    Mark(s)       |     Payment methods
www.coolblue.nl         PostNL          Free      Thuiswinkel           Ideal, Visa, Mastercard
www.bol.com             PostNL          Free      Thuiswinkel           Ideal, Visa, Mastercard
www.elektrosky.nl       PostNL         € 5,00     Webshop keurmerk      Ideal, Visa, Mastercard, Amex, PayPal
www.belsimpel.nl        PostNL, DPD    € 6,95     Thuiswinkel           Ideal, Visa, Mastercard
```

Comment: What are the contents of the xl file ?

Comment: Websites with some characteristics like payment methods and such. But like I said, it used to work and since the xml file didn't change I don't think the content is the problem?

Comment: If you can show me the columns and a few rows of the xl, I can try to run this code and see if the behaviour can be reproduced.

Comment: I edited my post and added the first 6 rows of my xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using `.internal_value`. By default Excel stores strings in a lookup table and keeps the index in the cell. You should be fine if you just use `.value`